# Read streaming data from server

Tags: shell-script, streaming

I have a server ip:port from where continuous data is coming. I want to read this data using shell script and want to transfer in some file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `netcat`:

```
nc <host> <port> > <filename>

# e.g.
nc time.nist.gov 13 > current_time
```

With bash you don't need `nc`. Bash has built-in network capabilities and you can do:

```
cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
```

Comment: HI @Macro: I tried nc but it does not seems to be returning anything. I pasted ip:port in browser and i can see continuous data getting printed on it. Is there any way to test connectivity first?

Comment: @Shashi Don't redirect to a file. Then you can interact with the service via terminal and send/receive data.

Comment: @Shashi, use the `-v` option with the command. Ex: `nc -v google.com 80`

Comment: Thanks Macro. It worked for me. I facing something strange issue here. I have centos vm from where nc command is not working but when i tried with machine where centos is installed , it worked perfectly. I checked network of my cent os vm; i am able to ping google from it.Anyways thanks for help.